# How to use sitemap.xml on main domain for subdomains?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have website with subdomains, example: example.com, de.example.com, fr.site.com ... language support. Is it correct to use one Sitemap.xml on main domain example.com?

**Example sitemap.xml**:

```
http://example.com/index
http://example.com/about
http://de.example.com/index
http://de.example.com/about
http://fr.example.com/index
http://fr.example.com/about
```

....
or will be correct to use sitemap for each subdomain?

Comment: Specifically see Unor's answer on the duplicate question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82743/   All URLs in a sitemap must be on the same subdomain where the sitemap is hosted.   You will have to create multiple sitemaps and host the sitemap for each subdomain on that subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll recommend you to create one sitemap per subdomain and use a [sitemaps index file](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en). That way you can see the [evolution in Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) for each subdomain.

I treat subdomain as images or videos (each in a separate sitemap).

[image]