# Master Sitemap holding child sitemaps on different domain

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I have a master sitemap, index.xml on `https://www.example.com/index.xml`

This XML contain childmaps pointing to a subdomain URL of mine like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
  <loc>https://sitemap.example.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-02-04T11:15:02.000Z</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
  <loc>https://sitemap.example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-02-04T11:15:02.000Z</lastmod>
</sitemap>
```

And the actual sitemap contains like:
`https://sitemap.example.com/sitemap2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/Yogua</loc>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
  <lastmod>2019-02-04T11:15:02.000Z</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Question:

1. Is there any problem doing above?
2. Do I need to add a property on google search console webmaster for `sitemap.example.com` to authorize my ownership for the subdomain?
3. Google notified me with an error as "General HTTP error: 404 not found
   HTTP Error: 404", is this because of #2 not in place?

PS: I have verified access for the GoogleBot for All the URLs.

Comment: Thanks Dan, for making the scenario more clear !!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there any problem doing above?

**Yes**.

"Google expects the [standard sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/) in all formats." - [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en)

"**all URLs listed in the Sitemap must use the same protocol and *reside on the same host as the Sitemap***. For instance, if the Sitemap is located at http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml, it can't include URLs from http://subdomain.example.com." - [sitemaps.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)

---

#### Edit:

Your XML sitemap example for `https://sitemap.example.com/sitemap2.xml` must only list URLs following the rule quoted above.

`<loc>https://www.example.com/Yogua</loc>` won't work due to the different subdomain.

Your XML sitemap *index*, on the other hand, is fine. That can list sitemaps across domains.

---

> 2. Do I need to add a property on google search console webmaster for sitemap.example.com to authorize my ownership for the subdomain?

<strike>No.</strike>

---

#### Edit:

Depends on the property type -- see [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en).

- URL-prefix property -- yes.
- Domain property -- no.

---

> 3. Google notified me with an error as "General HTTP error: 404 not found HTTP Error: 404", is this because of #2 not in place?

This is more likely because of #1. Then again that is some *incredibly* generic error text.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. Whilst the sitemaps protocol restricts sitemaps to the same host (and this may be a problem for "other" search engines). **"Google"** does permit you to have cross-site sitemaps, providing you have #2 Verified ownership of all properties in GSC. See the Google Help docs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en

Comment: I have seen the error of my ways. Thanks, @DocRoot.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there any problem doing above?

No, your sitemaps are absolutely correct. You can check this as a reference:

Master Sitemap: `https://www.simplilearn.com/sitemaps/sitemaps_production.xml`

Domain Sitemap: `https://br.simplilearn.com/sitemaps/br.sitemap_production.xml`

**Additional Notes:**

- If you're submitting URLs in the master sitemap, they can hold URLs from multiple sub-domains.
- If you're submitting a sub-domain sitemap, your sitemap should contain only the links related to the sub-domain to be relevant. **(This is applicable to Google and affects other search engines as stated by DocRoot)**

> 2. Do I need to add a property on google search console webmaster for sitemap.example.com to authorize my ownership for the subdomain?

Yes, validating your property will help you on ownership for the subdomain

> 3. Google notified me with an error as "General HTTP error: 404 not found HTTP Error: 404", is this because of #2 not in place?

What is this error about? Is this related to the sitemap? (Once you answer this, I'll update accordingly)

If you have not created the sitemap and have tried to submit it, of course 404 will occur.

Comment: The downvoter should have left a comment. This answer is mostly correct, although I wouldn't necessarily state "your sitemaps are absolutely correct" as it does contravene the sitemaps protocol, which will effect "other" search engines.  [**"Google"** does allow you to have cross-site sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en) providing you have #2 Verified all the properties in GSC. However, this is unique to Google AFAIK.

Comment: The OP was referring to Google, that is the reason, I stated correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Stack Exchange query](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82687/sitemaps-one-per-subdomain-or-one-for-the-base-domain) each subdomain is considered to be a separate domain and therefore needs a different sitemap.

And from [Matt Cutts blog](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/)

> Google uses subdomains for distinct products such news.google.com or
>   maps.google.com, for example

Comment: You should also read [unor's answer from the same question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82743/52912) - providing you verify ownership of the subdomain's in GSC then "Google" allows you to have cross-site sitemaps.

Comment: @DocRoot, thanks.  I don't know why I didn't see that when I read the post.  Thank you .